# Pixel-to-pixel conversion of .docx file to PDF

Tags: command-line, pdf, conversion, docx

I am looking for some type of DOCX to PDF converter that can be used through the command line.

I don't need any of the functionality of the original `.docx` to be preserved. I basically just want a pixel-to-pixel conversion. So in other words, just a conversion that takes the DOCX file as an image and sticks it into a PDF output.

Does this type of conversion exist anywhere? I have spent the last few hours trying to find this before asking, as to avoid asking a redundant question, but I have had no luck.

EDIT: Okay so for some more information. I am using some reporting software that best outputs to DOCX from DOCX. When outputting to PDF, there is some formatting problems with charts/graphs and what not. Now what I was thinking is, if I could run my reports to DOCX (which would be formatted exactly how I want them) than convert them to PDF than I would be in business. But when converting them to PDF, all that matters to me is that the PDF looks identical to DOCX document, but I dont need the functionality of a PDF. So in other words, is there some command line tool that could in simple terms take a "screenshot" of the word document and put that on a PDF.

Comment: Welcome to Super User, Sean! Can you explain why you need this (rather specific) functionality? Giving us a little more background might give you better answers.

Comment: Neither DOCX nor PDF is a raster format, so what's meant by "pixel-to-pixel" in this context is an open question. The more information you can give on the nature of what you're trying to do, the easier it'll be for someone to provide a helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you experiment with a few different PDF printer drivers to see if you get different results or that you tweak your DOCX file so that the conversion to PDF is more accurate. Both of those options would be better than a DOCX to Image to PDF conversion.

As for your request, you have a couple of options:

1. Manually take a screenshot of each page in your DOCX file
2. Use a DOCX to Image conversion tool or service (Google it)
3. Convert the image to PDF

However, it's likely that any DOCX to Image conversion tool is actually going to go through the same rendering process that the DOCX file goes through when being printed to PDF as the mechanics of printing to an image virtual printer and a PDF virtual printer are very similar.

So that really leaves you with the first option of taking a screenshot of each page manually -- unlikely to find a command line tool that does this as it is a little unusual -- or get the DOCX file into shape so that printing to PDF gives you the results you want.